# net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when trying to acccess server

Tags: node.js, server, client

I have a simple server and client for a simple (non security focused) login screen, But when i try to send a request from the client i get a error saying net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, how can i fix it?

Server (src/index.mjs):

```
import { createServer } from "http";

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 1337;

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "GET" && req.url === "/login") {
    const { username, password } = req.query;
    console.log("usr:" + username + "pass:" + password);
    // Perform authentication logic here
    if (
      username === "read_password" &&
      password === "security_isnt_what_i_want"
    ) {
      // Authentication successful
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      res.end("Login successful");
    } else {
      // Authentication failed
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      res.end("Login failed");
    }
  } else {
    // Handle other requests
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.end("Not Found");
  }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Client (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <script>
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };

    let loginForm = `
    <form>
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    `;

    let loginDiv = document.createElement("div");
    loginDiv.innerHTML = loginForm;

    document.body.appendChild(loginDiv);
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let username = document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value;
      let password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
      xhr.open("POST", "https://127.0.0.1:1337/login", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Expected (Client input: read_password, security_isnt_what_i_want):

No output in developer console.

Got (Client Same input.):

```
POST https://127.0.0.1:1337/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing I see, is that you have GET request in IF check here

```
if (req.method === "GET" && req.url === "/login")
```

But you are trying to do POST request, so nothing would be outputted in console.
Let me know if issue still persists

The correct code for this would be:

```
import { createServer } from "http";

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 1337;

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  // req.url looks like this /login?username=read_password&password=security_isnt_what_i_want'
  const url = req.url.split('?')
  const originUrl = url[0]
  console.log('this is originUrl', originUrl)

  if (req.method === "POST" && originUrl === "/login") {
    let queryParams = new URLSearchParams(url[1]);
    const username = queryParams.get('username')
    const password = queryParams.get('password')

    
    console.log("usr:" + username + "pass:" + password);
    // Perform authentication logic here
    if (
      username === "read_password" &&
      password === "security_isnt_what_i_want"
    ) {
      // Authentication successful
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      res.end("Login successful");
    } else {
      // Authentication failed
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      res.end("Login failed");
    }
  } else {
    // Handle other requests
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.end("Not Found");
  }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Now making post request here: http://127.0.0.1:1337/login?username=read_password&password=security_isnt_what_i_want
will return login successfull

Comment: its now POST http://127.0.0.1:1337/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @WinwinTheDumbguy Does server running get logged in console?
Also could you log in createServer before if statement, if anything is received?

Comment: yes.     const { username, password } = req.query;
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'req.query' as it is undefined.
    at Server.<anonymous> (file:///(insert where the file is here)/src/index.mjs:8:13)
    at Server.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1067:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)

Node.js v19.5.0

Comment: and can you explain the second question better i dont understand

Comment: @WinwinTheDumbguy Okay as it seems, req.query is undefined. Native NodeJS does not add that property. You can either use express, or I am going to run this code locally myself in around 30 minutes and verify how to add query property to request

Comment: As i have no idea what is express, i will wait the 30 mins.

Comment: @WinwinTheDumbguy Edited Response, try that.
Express is framework for NodeJS https://expressjs.com/. It helps you simplify a lot of stuff you have to write in nodeJS.

Comment: Now i get a CORS error, Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/login' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
index.html:41          POST http://127.0.0.1:1337/login net::ERR_FAILED 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: @WinwinTheDumbguy Instead of res.setHeader, include this:
```
      res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  });

```
This should be enough to accept this as answer for your solution

Comment: still doesnt work... [picture](https://prnt.sc/vyCjbp3MHZWn)

Comment: @WinwinTheDumbguy When you type in browser url, you do GET request. Update if statement to this req.method === "GET